# Detail view Controller with Parsing the web-service(JSON)

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

In my App, I have a list of news to be shown and I'm using custom tableview which has a Title, Thumbnail image and more button. On Tapping more button, it will take to the detail view which has description. I've parsed the JSON response for listing the feed in page. But I'm strucked with the detail page. Following is my code:

.m file

```
@interface NewsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSMutableArray *mArray;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSDictionary *nDic;
@end

@implementation NewsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://almithaq.mawaqaademo11.com/API.svc/getNews" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    self.nDic = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    self.mArray = self.nDic[@"News"];
    [self.mTab reloadData];
    NSLog(@"response dateJSON: %@", self.mArray);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}

#pragma mark - TableConfiguration
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.mArray count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *Identifier = @"MyIdentifier";


NewsCell *cell12 = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
if (cell12 == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell12 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}


cell12.newsDescription.text = [[self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
cell12.newsTitle.text = [[self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];

cell12.newsThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",[[self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"NewsImage"]]]]];

cell12.newsMore.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell12.newsMore addTarget:self action:@selector(NewsClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell12;

  }
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
return 220;
  }

  -(void)backButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
  {
if (sender.tag <= 25)
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

 }

  -(void)NewsClicked:(UIButton *)sender
   {
if (sender.tag <= 25) {
    NewsDetails *view1 = [[NewsDetails   alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewsDetails" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view1 animated:YES];
}}
```

Advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the problem is with getting to (or whatever it is thats wrong with) the detail page. Also, take time to format the code in your question so it's easily readable.

Comment: Sorry For that @Wain running out off time , my question is tapping no the more button it should take to the detail page and how to parse the web-services for the detail view

Comment: What'll you do when anyone invokes `NewsClicked` method?

Comment: It will take to the another VC which has UIImage view for the image and UIText view for the Description.

Comment: Okay! But, how will you get the image data and description as there is no Webservice calls for JSON in `NewsClicked` method?

Comment: that's what i'm in search off need guidance on that where we should call the webservice?. i need just like TimesNow app if clicking on listing page that it will take to the detail view.

Comment: And you're using storyboard / XIB / only code? And you shouldn't ask both about view controller loading and management and webservice handling in one question. The question lacks the details for anyone to answer currently and is too broad.

Comment: my apologies for that . i'm using XIbs

Comment: @Wain : and the web-service for listing news in GET and in that ID for each news is provided and using that ID should fetch the detailed Image and Description using POST method